# Android: Overriding context menu

Tags: android, onclick, contextmenu

I have created my own contextual menu (contextual action bar) and I want to override (and disable) original contextual menu.

So in my activity I put:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    mActionBarHelper.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.clear();
}
```

mActionBarHelper processes the menu and displays items on action bar.

I clear the menu to not show as classic contextual menu. But it call's onClick event when the menu is cleared. Please, is there a way how to force the activity not calling onClick and not showing original menu ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

One workAround can be to initialize the custom menu class at the onClick of the menu button.This might help http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/07/overwrite-menu-key-to-create-custom.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this article is about classic menu. But I need to know how to override contextual menu (long click on item)